# Cannot read property 'string' of undefined | React.PropTypes | LayoutPropTypes.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

After deleting and reinstalling my node_modules folder, I'm facing an issue that I don't understand in LayoutPropTypes.js file.

In `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/LayoutPropTypes.js`
The following variable is undefined : `var ReactPropTypes = require('React').PropTypes;`

react-native: 0.45.1
react: 16.0.0-alpha.12

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[React.PropTypes is now deprecated:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

> Note: React.PropTypes is deprecated as of React v15.5. Please use the
>   prop-types library instead.

You need to add the [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) package separately now. The error most likely just started to show up because you deleted your `node_modules` folder and then reinstalled everything which upgraded your `react` version.

Comment: I have added prop-types into my project, but I still have this problem. I tried to reinstall node, it was no use. And now, I even couldn't run the demo of react native. I want to know how can I degrade the version of react?

Comment: Fixed by restarting computer :(

Comment: @NicolasMeienberger `yarn add react@16.0.0-alpha.12`

Answer (score 15):

React is no more shipped with PropTypes. You will need to install it.

First install the `prop-types` package by running `npm i prop-types --save`.

Next use the `prop-types` package into your component like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export const AwesomeComponent = props => {
    return(
        <h1>Hello {props.name}</h1>
    )
}

AwesomeComponent.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

Or simply use an interface if you are using Typescript like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface IAwesomeComponentProps {
    name: string
} 

export const AwesomeComponent: React.FC<IAwesomeComponentProps> = props => {
    return(
        <h1>Hello {props.name}</h1>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Are you absolutely sure you are using react `16.0.0-alpha.12`?

Check your **package.json** if you have a `^` before the react version, if you have, it probably have installed the latest react version, which currently is `16.0.0-alpha.13`, in which it breaks as you say (just had the problem myself). Having the `^` before the version, allows it to install newer minor and patch versions. [You can read more about it here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver).

To keep it at the exact version you specify, simply remove the `^` before the version, so that your package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
  }
```

Remember to re-install your node_modules after your changes.

Comment: I have the same issue in alpha.13, when back to alpha.12 is OK!

Answer (score 2):

I have the similar problem, no solution. Answers talking about 'prop-types' package are meaningless, the problem is come from react-native source code. That is not an option to manually fix react native source in node_modules folder.

Comment: What I do not fully understand, if I create a fresh app with ```react-native init``` then the app runs well.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can update to react-native 0.46.4, just follow along this guide: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

my package.json looks like this:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.46.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of defining the value for component as like this:
propName: React.PropTypes.string

DEFINE LIKE THIS
propName: PropTypes.string

and finally save it.