# Why am I getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactPropTypes.string') error?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Here's the thing, I'm dealing with like 10 `.js` files so posting them here would be way too much.  My question is, what are the possible reasons I'm getting this error?  I understand it's somewhat of a vague question, but I can't find an answer anywhere to this.

On top of this, there are absolutely no errors in any of these `.js` files.  It's only when I hit `Run` to see the result of my code in the simulator do I see the error (pic below).

My apologies again if it's too vague, I just don't know where else to turn.

Could it be in this file?  I think it's all correct here.  I just have a slight feeling this file is the problem.

Here's `Router.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navigator } from 'react-native';
import Home from './Home';
import Location from './Location';
import Interest from './Interest';
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup';

export default class Router extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  configureScene(route, routeStack) {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid;
  }

renderScene(route, navigator) {
  if (route.name === 'Home') {
    return (
      <Home
      navigator={navigator}
      {...route.passProps}
      />
    );
  }
  if (route.name === 'Location') {
    return (
      <Location
      navigator={navigator}
      {...route.passProps}
      />
    );
  }
  if (route.name === 'Interest') {
    return (
      <Interest
      navigator={navigator}
      {...route.passProps}
      />
    );
  }
  if (route.name === 'Login') {
    return <Login navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
  }
  if (route.name == 'Signup') {
      return ( <Signup navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} /> )
    }
}

render() {
  return (
    <Navigator
      configureScene={this.configureScene}
      initialRoute={{ name: 'Home', title: 'Home' }}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
    />
  );
}

}
```

[Weird error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHTVD.png)

Comment: My guess is that it should have been `React.PropTypes.string`

Comment: @Xotic750 What do you mean?  I can't catch your drift here.  My error is exactly what the picture says in my original post.

Comment: If not what Xotic750 said, then you are probably passing a prop that is `undefined` or not passing a prop at all to the component. Figure out which component is throwing that error to track down the issue.

Comment: A typo, you are missing the `.`

Comment: @MichaelCheng I posted the file that's potentially causing this error.  I might be wrong though.

Comment: can you do a "find all files" search for `ReactPropTypes` then fix the typo if its there

Comment: LayoutPropTypes.js is not a file that belongs to you?

Comment: @azium nope.  I don't have a file of that name.  How would I do a "find all files" search?

Comment: @klobbaks If you're on Mac or Linux and have access to a terminal, you can cd to the directory with your source code and run `grep -r 'ReactPropTypes' *.js`. Alternatively, most editors have the option to search your workspace/folder.

Comment: this might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573199/cannot-read-property-string-of-undefined-react-proptypes-layoutproptypes-j

Comment: @MichaelCheng Ok, I just ran that and nothing happened.

Comment: `React.PropTypes` is deprecated. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573199/cannot-read-property-string-of-undefined-react-proptypes-layoutproptypes-j

Comment: It's deprecated but not removed until v16, current v15.6.1 What version is the OP using? No idea.

Comment: Latest `react-native` release: `"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/eb7d3bae26067d4358100e555168c5012dd7c7f8/package.json

Comment: @klobbaks Sorry messed up the grep command. Should have tested it first. This should work: `grep -r --include=\*.js --exclude-dir=node_modules 'ReactPropTypes' ./`