# TS2339: Property 'PropTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof React' when porting to Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm currently converting a javascript/react project to a typescript/react/redux project.

I'm currently having a problem with this file:

```
import React from 'react';
import GoldenLayout from 'golden-layout';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Default from '../modules/m-Default/Default';

interface GoldenLayoutWrapperProps {}

interface GoldenLayoutWrapperState {}

class GoldenLayoutWrapper extends React.Component <GoldenLayoutWrapperProps, GoldenLayoutWrapperState> {

    public layout;
    static contextTypes = {
        store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    private wrapComponent(Component, store) {
        class Wrapped extends React.Component {
            render () {
                return (
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <Component {...this.props}/>
                    </Provider>
                )
            }
        }
        return Wrapped;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var layout = new GoldenLayout(this.layoutConfig, this.layout);

        layout.registerComponent('Default', this.wrapComponent(Default, this.context.store));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="golden-layout-wrapper" ref={input => this.layout = input}/>
        )
    }

    private layoutConfig = {}
}

   export default GoldenLayoutWrapper;
```

When I attempt to compile, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/GoldenLayoutWrapper.tsx:18:22 
TS2339: Property 'PropTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.
```

After some searcing, some people suggested to give `contextTypes` a static modifier, which I attempted, but the problem still persists.

What could be the problem?

Comment: which version of reactjs are you using ?

Comment: @Aaqib I'm using react 16.0.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you are using React v16.0.0 , You need to make use of `prop-types` as it is treated a separate library since React v15.5

You can install it via npm as a project dependency

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

And then inside your component where you want to use it :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
```

Instead of `React.PropTypes` you can directly use PropTypes

You can read more about prop-types [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here for full details: [Cannot read property 'string' of undefined | React.PropTypes | LayoutPropTypes.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573199/cannot-read-property-string-of-undefined-react-proptypes-layoutproptypes-j/44573437#44573437)

In short, as of React v15.5 `React.PropTypes` is deprecated. You'll need to install the [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) package from npm.