# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am trying to install storybook on react UI. When I run this command:
npm run storybook

I get the following error:
[image]

I did refer to these links
[Cannot read property 'string' of undefined | React.PropTypes | LayoutPropTypes.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573199/cannot-read-property-string-of-undefined-react-proptypes-layoutproptypes-j)
 and tried to apply the solutions suggested but its still giving me the same error. I installed the prop type library explicitly and removed the ^ before react version. The versions of react and prop types are as follows :
"react": "16.3.2",
"prop-types": "^15.6.2"

My code looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { configure } from '@kadira/storybook';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '../components/Button';

storiesOf('Button', module)
    .add('with text', () => (
        <Button onClick={action('clicked')}>Hello Button</Button>
    ))
    .add('with some emoji', () => (
        <Button onClick={action('clicked')}><span role="img" aria-label="so cool">   </span></Button>
    ));
```

Am i still missing out some step ?

Comment: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/1935

Comment: already tried this solution. doesn't change anything

Comment: It's hard to know your issue. It will be easier to create a repo that only contain enough code to generate the error.