# reacter router dom is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router, react-router-dom

i don't know why this program is not working on my computer while other PC does
so when i want to running this program it gives one error is given below,
so try to hep for fix it...

**index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Posts from './components/posts';
import Profile from './components/profile';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Home</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Route path="/posts" component={Posts}></Route>
            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}></Route>
          </div>
         </BrowserRouter>
    , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

**posts.js**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Posts extends Component {
      render() {
        return <div>Posts</div>
      }
    }

    export default Posts;
```

**profile.js**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Profile extends Component {
      render() {
        return <div>Profile</div>
      }
    }

    export default Profile;
```

but it shows the error something like this in the microsogt edge...

[image: error]

it shows error in mozilla firefox like this...
[image]

error is in bundle.js file...so here one is the full error message from the bundle.js file which is given below

**bundle.js**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'string' of undefined | React.PropTypes | LayoutPropTypes.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573199/cannot-read-property-string-of-undefined-react-proptypes-layoutproptypes-j)

Comment: @mrpanchal Surprisingly above code perfectly worked for me. Could you please add stack-trace of the error. As shown in above image click on bundle.js link, it will show where it is actually throwing an error. I hope you have posted all your code, if not please post it. It will help to solve the problem.

Comment: @RahulRaut i have edited my post and added the bundle.js image which is showing the error...hope u will find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like versioning issue. As Ruoyan mentioned in his answer prop-types has been moved out from react. It is separate dependency now. Looks like your react-router-dom is on older version. Please have a look at my package.json file and cross check your versions against it. You can simply copy dependencies section and paste your package.json file and run npm install command.

```
{
   "name": "react-app",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
   "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
   "react": "^16.4.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
   "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
   "style-loader": "^0.21.0"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`prop-types` may not be installed because of a variety of dependency problems. Try deleting `node_modules` and run `npm install again`.

And more errors,  you need to check `/node_modules/react-router-dom/es/BrowserRouter.js` whether this file import prop-types module correctly.

Comment: i have deleted and installed once again node modules but it still doesn't work... and i have edited my post to show error in the mozilla firefox

Comment: So，you need to check `BrowserRouter.js` file. I guess it should be the issue of the `react-router` version, check the dependency.  The `PropTypes` have been moved from React to their own package prop-types